# UICollectionView allow multiple selection for specific section

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

Is there a way to allow multiple selection only for a specific section? The code below affects all sections.

```
[self.collectionView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
```

Should i keep track of the states and do something in `didSelect`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control cell selection by implementing [`shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:) in your `UICollectionViewDelegate` implementation.

For example, this code allows selection of any number of cells at section 1 but only one cell of any other section:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems.count == 0 && indexPath.section == 1;
}
```

If you require a more complex behavior you can implement it at [`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:). For example, this code will allow multiple selection only at section 1 and will allow only one cell selected at any other section:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
        return;

    NSArray<NSIndexPath*>* selectedIndexes = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndexes.count; i++) {
        NSIndexPath* currentIndex = selectedIndexes[i];
        if (![currentIndex isEqual:indexPath] && currentIndex.section != 1) {
            [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:currentIndex animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ShouldSelect Will always return YES; Nothing to do there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, check my edit to see if it fits your needs.